# Zend: Is it possible to set cookie on a mobile device using Web Services?

Tags: iphone, web-services, zend-framework, cookies

I have a Iphone application that uses my web services (coded in Zend) to authenticate login credentials. It sends the login credentials to a URL of my web service via POST.

Now is there any way in Zend to set cookie in the Iphone local storage device, through web services. To be more clear i want to set cookie after user is authenticated with user info on the iphone device when it makes the http POST request Can this be possible? Why or why not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not a solution if i assume you need to keep the credential for each new request on the webservice.

You should keep an hash of the session or of the credential once the user is authenticated, then send it as a parameter on each new request, beside you'll be able to keep track of your users.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['mac']))     
session_id($_GET['mac']);
else
die(session_id());
```

If your mobile client send request without mac (first request) it well get mac . Once you 
have the mac then simply send in each request which will give you cookie-session like functionality.